# Subversion release management system

Tags: svn, release-management

We are using Subversion and things are going well with it.  We are actively using branches and tags as appropriate to indicate releases at the appropriate levels.

However, we are looking for a release management tool.  Essentially, what it needs to do is relatively simple:

1. Grab the relevant code from Subversion (based on a tag).
2. Do preparatory work (for example: put it in a tar, exclude certain directories).
3. Audit trail ("User X is performing this release")
4. Email trail (Send an email indicating a release request).
5. Perform the install.

We've previously created our own web-based system to handle this sort of thing (release requests).  Really, it's more of the *workflow* that we are after.

I'm aware that SVN itself can be used to update different servers, but this isn't appropriate for us.  We don't want production servers updating using SVN itself due to the security tiers in use.  Currently, a tar file is extracted as appropriate for a release by our operations team.  Developers do not have this level of access, so there is a degree of seperation.

We don't need a *build* management tool, as the software is in Perl and we are happy with how that is going.  It is all safe and sound in Subversion.  The key is the deployment, once everything is tagged and ready!

Looking forward to your input.

Comment: Id just use Jenkins were it me :-)

Comment: Do you have unit tests? Are they run before the release? The best is to use a thing like Jenkins and write a Perl Script to create the archives etc. Or in that case it might be worth to take a look at ant for such task?

Comment: It's not so much the building of a release I am after here.  It's more "We have the release, now what?".  We have multiple SVN projects and multiple target environments.  It's a way of getting the releases onto those environments, in an audited and controlled way, that I am after. This is where we have written our own web interface system, although the installs are done with FTP and tar by our operations team.  Is there a product which can make this easy, essentially?

Answer (score 1):

I don't tend to use these kind of things as I find the effort required to keep the deployment up to date and correct is quite difficult, though I guess that depends on your software and the kind of deployment targets you have (eg no way would we automate deployment to clients in my arena!).

However, there is [Go](http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/go-agile-release-management) from Thoughtworks that might suit you, or [uDeploy](http://www.urbancode.com/html/products/deploy;jsessionid=27D2E9240832A6C8F3731445F2BDCC10). I would be very careful about using expensive tools, the one I used was so dreadful we binned it as soon as we could.

You might want to take a quick look at Jenkins though, I know it would solve a solved problem for you, but it can (in addition to builds - it can still run your perl scripts) package up the build and do the email and audit workflow you wanted. It might be able to run the install, but that depends on your installation system. Jenkins is excellent software and worth looking into anyway. I think it would fit into your existing system with only a minor compromise on your part.

For actual deployment, you could use something like [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/) that will also give you some feedback on steps completed.

Answer (score 0):

A traditional approach is the use of `automake` for the distribution tarball, followed by a simple shell script performing the additional steps. This should be written up fairly quickly, and is easily changed.